# JavaFX: NullPointerException by setting text to textarea in another window (fxml), same controller

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, window, fxml

i have 2 fxml files, LayoutGUI.fxml (main window) and LayoutError.fxml (just a window with 2 textarea's and a ok button). Both have the same controller. I would like to show an occured exception in the  LayoutError.fxml. But if i use the setText("") methods of the textareas in the controller i get a NullPointerException. If i set the text in the button clicked action in the controller, there is no exception.

```
public void showError(String headline,String errorTxt,String stackTrace)
{
    Parent root;
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("application/view/LayoutError.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Error Message!");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450,300));
        stage.show();
        error_txtarea_Stacktrace.setText(stackTrace);
        error_txtarea_error.setText(errorTxt);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }   
}
```

If i set text here there is no exception. Is it posible that the components not initialized at this time or why can i set the text in the button clicked method and not if i show the window?

```
    @FXML
public void errorButtonOKAction(ActionEvent event)
{
    // get a handle to the stage and close it
    //Stage stage = (Stage) error_btnOK.getScene().getWindow();
    //stage.close();
    error_txtarea_Stacktrace.setText("dasds");
    error_txtarea_error.setText("dsds");
}
```

Controller is defined in the error.fxml and the textarea's have Id's.

Comment: You don't actually have the same controller for both FXML files; each one has its own controller instance - they just both happen to be instances of the same class. This is almost always a bad idea; you should create different controller classes for each FXML file.